# P&T Asset and Google Cloud Storage

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, google

I've created a Google Cloud Storage Bucket and enabled what I believe to be the right place for the Secret and Access ID - however, I'm getting the following error whenever I try to save and the location doesn't appear in my assets folder for view:

`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$body
Filename: lib/Assets_GC.php
Line Number: 1993`

I can't actually find any instructions on how to configure/setup google cloud hosting, so I'm a little stuck as to whether I've done the right thing or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the error is being caused by. P&T may have some more info for you.

In the meantime, you might try using the config overrides for Assets to see if that works instead. This if you're using a master config of some sort. If no master config then disregard this answer.

You can setup Google Cloud Storage via a System Configuration Override using [assets_source_settings](https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/using/config.html). This is similar to EE's file upload_preference ([v3](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#upload-preferences))([v2](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#upload-preferences)). So, if you had two locations to setup, for [Focus Lab Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) on EE2, it would look something like this:

```
$env_config['assets_source_settings'] = array(
    1 => array(
        'access_key_id'     => 'your_id',
        'secret_access_key' => 'your_access_key',
        'bucket'            => 'your_bucket',
        'url_prefix'        => 'your_url_prefix',
        'subfolder'         => 'your_subfolder',
    ),
    2 => array(
        'access_key_id'     => 'your_id',
        'secret_access_key' => 'your_access_key',
        'bucket'            => 'your_bucket',
        'url_prefix'        => 'your_url_prefix',
        'subfolder'         => 'your_subfolder',
    )
);
```

Note: I'm not sure you can setup a source without doing it in the CP first, however, could be worth a try.